# Can not run make command in Dev-cpp application

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make, dev-c++

I have a very simple example named *HelloWorld* and located in folder *"C:/HelloWorld"* in Dev-Cpp as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, if I press F11 (**Compile and run**) then the program executes normally.
But I want to execute this program in an another way: use **make** command!!!

I have known that the syntax to run *make* command : **make -f [make file name]**. In Dev-Cpp, this command is **make -f "Makefile.win"**. So I jump into *HelloWorld* folder and type as follows:

[image: make command]

The console displays many errors relating to included headers.

[image: make result]

How can I run make command without any errors? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

not so easy with make :)
at first if you use msvc or DevCpp try to find "Export makefile" 
at second you need to configure your compilator(s).
at third you need to show what Makefile.win contains.

man:
http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html
gcc:
https://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your link is very useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

All right. There are something wrong with my **make** command.

The problem is I had installed two versions of gcc in my computer. The *HelloWorld* example is compiled and built with the latest GCC version.

However, the **make** command I had type is belonged to the older GCC version. As a result, it leads to many errors.

In order to run *make* command correctly, I must to use the right **make** command that is defined in Dev-Cpp (below picture): **mingw32-make.exe**

[image: right make command]